# How to animate active tab when it changes

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a tab list of `li` items. when an item is active the li item has rounded corners and box shadow. I want to be able to show animation of the active pill moving to its next position when it changes but dont quite know how to achieve it. this is what i've done.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 44px;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  transition:all 0.7s;
  &.active {
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    transition:all .5s;
  }

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
<ul>
   <li class="active"><span>one</span></li>
   <li><span>two</span></li>
</ul>
```

I have a react codesandbox here where u can see it in action https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-shannon-8yfuf?file=/src/TabItem.jsx

Comment: Where is the run option in codesandbox , I am not able to find that and can't run the changes

Comment: What is it that changes? I can see you have set transitions on everything but I can't see what has changed.

Comment: @Rana there's no run option. it  changes automatically. you can also do ctrl + save to run the changes again

Comment: @AHaworth not sure i totally understand your question. all am trying to do is create a moving transition when the active pill changes from item to item. I added a codesandbox for you to see

Comment: any ideas about this?

Comment: I can see transition property settings but on their own they do nothing. Which other properties are you changing to cause an animating effect?

Comment: It needs javascript code... you should get the current tab index, then with CSS feature "transition: translateX ... " move the shadow box to the next tab. for example, if you want to change tab 1 to tab 3 you should set "transition: translateX(2*tabWidth)"

Comment: @AHaworth thats what i am trying to figure know what other property to use to animate it

Comment: @Mohsen007 can u write it in the codesandbox?

Comment: Do you want it to grow in size then shrink, to move slightly in some direction then back or....

Comment: @user3775998 here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-stallman-xsjp7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you tagged the question with `css` I am answering with what I would do in your case (if I understood right the animation you want to do).

I don't know about `reactjs` (apologise in advance) but I think if you want to "move" the effect create to your `<a>` element to next... it's goign to be difficult (if possible at all).

I would place a box under your link with the style you are actually giving to the link, positioned `absolute` and just by clicking in the links with a simple `javascript` change the position to move it under the other link.

like this:

```js
$(".li1").on("click", function(){
        $(".btn").attr('class', 'btn');
    $(".btn").addClass("eff1");
});
$(".li2").on("click", function(){
    $(".btn").attr('class', 'btn');
    $(".btn").addClass("eff2");
});
$(".li3").on("click", function(){
    $(".btn").attr('class', 'btn');
    $(".btn").addClass("eff3");
});
$(".li4").on("click", function(){
        $(".btn").attr('class', 'btn');
    $(".btn").addClass("eff4");
});
```

```css
div {
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;}
ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    border-radius: 44px;     
}
li {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
.btn {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius: 44px; 
  height:calc(100% - 8px);
  width:90px;
  position:absolute;
  top:4px;
  left:4px;
  transition:left 0.51s ease;
}
.eff1 {left:4px;}
.eff2 {left:90px;}
.eff3 {left:180px;}
.eff4 {left:270px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class=" XTdVG">
    <li class="li1"><a href="#">wwwww</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#">wwwww</a></li>
    <li class="li3"><a href="#">wwwww</a></li>
    <li class="li4"><a href="#">wwwww</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Note: if your links are goign to have different widths... just add it to the `.eff1, .eff2, .eff3, .eff4`